# Get error description with ftp_connect and ftp_login

Tags: php, error-handling

I am trying a FTP connection with `ftp_connect` and `ftp_login`.  But because of an issue that I don't know, I'm not able to do it.  If I'm not wrong, `ftp_connect` and `ftp_login` just return `true` if the connection is performed, and `false` if the connection wasn't possible.

Is it possible to get the error description of `ftp_connect` and `ftp_login` when they return `false`?

```
$objConn = ftp_connect("ftp.server.com");
$objLogin = ftp_login($objConn,"user","password");

if((!$objConn) || (!$objLogin)){
    //Show error description here
    die("Error");
}else{
    echo "Connected!";
}
```

Comment: [`error_get_last()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-get-last.php) but you will have to check after each function call.

Comment: If you are logging or displaying warnings the `ftp_login()` will throw a warning if it fails.